# jQuery mobile is not displaying selects and buttons properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

At some pages jquerymobile select and buttons are shown twice.
Ive compared the code with other pages that are working ok but dont get to figure out where the problem is.
Can you please help me?
This is the code for a bad-displaying webpage and here is a printscreen http://i49.tinypic.com/34g7ybn.png.
Thanks!!

```
<div data-role="page" id="two" >
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
    <a href="#one" data-icon="arrow-l"  data-ajax="false">Volver</a>
    <h1>Mis autos</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px;" >
    <div name="mensaje_error_sistema" id="mensaje_error_sistema" style="display: none;">
        <div data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="b">
            <div class="ui-corner-all ui-body-e" style="padding:5px 15px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <p id="mensaje_error_sistema_txt" name="mensaje_error_sistema_txt" >.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form id="forms-alta-auto" method="post" action="index.php">                
        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="agregaauto">          
        <input type="text"   name="marca"  id="marca"  value="" placeholder="Marca"  onclick='$("#mensaje_error_sistema").hide();' />
        <input type="text"   name="modelo" id="modelo" value="" placeholder="Modelo" onclick='$("#mensaje_error_sistema").hide();' />

        <select name="color" id="color" data-native-menu="false" onclick='$("#mensaje_error_sistema").hide();'>
            <option value=''>Color</option>
            <option>Amarillo</option>
            <option>Azul</option>
            <option>Beige</option>
            <option>Blanco</option>
            <option>Bordo</option>
            <option>Celeste</option>
            <option>Champagne</option>
            <option>Gris</option>
            <option>Marr&oacute;n</option>
            <option>Negro</option>
            <option>Ocre</option>
            <option>Plateado</option>
            <option>Rojo</option>
            <option>Verde</option>
            <option>Violeta</option>
            <option>Otro</option>
        </select>

        <input name="patente" id="patente" placeholder="Patente" value="" type="text"  onclick='$("#mensaje_error_sistema").hide();' />
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" data-theme="b" id="agregar-auto" style="margin-top: 10px !important; margin-bottom: 10px !important;">Agregar el auto</button>

    </form>

</div>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div><div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-mini="true" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%;"><h3 style="font-size: 12px;">&copy; 2012 CompartiendoAuto.com</h3></div>
```

Comment: Have you validated your HTML? I see a `</fieldset>` and no `<fieldset>`.